# How to convert a Uint8Array to a mp3 formatted file to be saved

Tags: aws-sdk-nodejs

I am running with node.js 6.11.2. I am not running in a browser. I am trying to use the aws-sdk polly speechSynthesis service.   The service returns a Uint8array as the audio data. lets call it audioData. I wish to convert this file, audioData, to a properly formatted audio file in mp3 format so I can cache it locally. I then wish to play the file on a raspberry Pi. How does one convert the Uint8Array to a properly formatted mp3 file?  I tried audioData.toString() but that file could not be played.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about speechsynthesis, but you could write the array data to standard out and pipe to [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/).

From stdout:

`node script.js|ffmpeg -f s8 -i pipe:0 file.mp3`

Or you could first write the array to a file:

`ffmpeg -f s8 -i audioData file.mp3`

Note that the default samplerate is 44100Hz, if audio from speechsynthesis is different use the ar option to alter the expected samplerate:

```
ffmpeg -f s8 -ar [samplerate] -i [input] file.mp4
```

Different audio types can be found at https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types
Replace s8 in the above commands with the appropriate audio type.